# Trouble Getting Started with Fabric and Twitter Kit

Tags: android, android-studio, twitter-fabric

I just installed Fabric for Android Studio but I'm having a problem getting it to work.

In my code when I try add this:

```
import com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetui.TweetTimelineListAdapter;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetui.UserTimeline;
```

these classes are not recognized. I tried to resolve this by adding to my gradle file:

```
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:1.3.1@aar') {
transitive = true;
}
```

but still it's not working. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: What error message do you get? Do you have the correct dependencies set up in your build.gradle file?

Answer (score 2):

Your class imports say you're using *TweetUI KIT* in your app. To use this api you will also have to install **TweeiUI Kit** along with *Twitter Core Kit* in your `build.gradle` file as shown below.

```
dependencies {
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-ui:1.11.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:1.7.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

Reference : https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/tweet-ui.html